# How can this SQL query be more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql 5.7
linux

The query below takes about 210 seconds on 9000 records. Not really desirable performance.

The data table has these fields:

```
login_attempt_id integer
user_id integer
login_attempt_data datetime
login_attempt_ip string`
```

I wish to query the data to find the number of IPs that have failed login. For example:

```
109 119.27.191.202
93  118.25.146.128
83  132.232.31.117
81  132.232.160.234
```

The query:

```
select count(t0.login_attempt_ip) as `ip_count`, t0.login_attempt_ip 
  from sohne_sma_v4.wp_login_fails t0
  where t0.login_attempt_ip in
  (select distinct t1.login_attempt_ip from sohne_sma_v4.wp_login_fails t1
    where 20 <
    (select count(t2.login_attempt_ip) from sohne_sma_v4.wp_login_fails t2
       where t2.login_attempt_ip like t1.login_attempt_ip
    )
  )
  and datediff(now(), t0.login_attempt_date) < 15
  group by t0.login_attempt_ip
  order by ip_count desc;
```

I can guess the time is spent in the two inner queries.

What is a better way to achieve this query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: `t2.login_attempt_ip like t1.login_attempt_ip`, the way you have it coded and given the data you're showing, is the same as `t2.login_attempt_ip =  t1.login_attempt_ip` except that `LIKE` is inherently slower. Why are you using `LIKE` here?

Comment: Using "=" instead of "like" made little difference. I assumed the IP address was treated as a string because of all the dots.

Comment: you can use Join and don't use sub query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont really need all these subqueries.

You can just user `GROUP BY...HAVING` to keep grouped items having count more than 20.

Something like this should work

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vCMPWJaRxeSPVVDNSPVhcD/0

```
SELECT COUNT(t.login_attempt_id) AS ip_count,t.login_attempt_ip  FROM sohne_sma_v4.wp_login_fails t 
WHERE datediff(now(), t.login_attempt_date) < 15
GROUP BY t.login_attempt_ip HAVING (ip_count> 20 )
ORDER BY ip_count DESC;
```

Comment: Outstanding! That runs so much more quickly.

Thank you.